# Preload div once images, javascript files are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to work with jQuery libraries to preload content, the usual issue I ran into was that once all content is preloaded it displays a div however for a split seconds you can still see "bad looking" content as javascript wasn't applied to it yet, and than it changes to what it should look like. It's hard to explain. Basically I'm trying to display div (`<div class="text"></div>`) on a page once whole page is loaded, so images, javascript files etc.. I found really good example of what I wan't over here

http://tympanus.net/codrops/collective/collective-58/

You can see that grid / content is only displayed once everything is loaded up, before that users get a loading image as indication to wait, that's exactly what I try to achieve. I tried looking at a source, but it seems that a "preload" script is somewhere within other scripts, and has lots of unnecessary code (for me). so could you please suggest a lightweight jQuery solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:none` for your div initially and display a loading gif.

```
$(window).load(function() { 
   $('#yourGifID').hide();
   $('#yourDivID').show(); // will be called when everything is loaded
});
```

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

Comment: Cool it didn't work with display: none; (some markup need's to be visible in order for other things to work) but worked with visibility :) Any chance you can throw in a loading image for while content is being loaded?

Comment: sure, you can display a loading image, you just need to hide that when everything is loaded

Comment: That's because display:none doesn't apply the css or any styling until it's display:block; You only want to use display:none if you want the element to not take up any invisible space on the page.

Comment: @MohammadAdil for some reason doesn't seem to work in firefox, just displays content straight away.. I'm on os x 10.8 with firefox version 19.0.2

Comment: This is wrong answer. "Display:none" will not preload... It has to be "visibility: hidden" or you can hide it using negative absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

For the div that is giving you trouble, why not set its visibility to "hidden" in the html and then in the javascript, after everything is ready, change it to "visible"

html:

```
<div class="text" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

js:

```
$(".text").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what one of the solutions I used before offered, however it seemed that it took effect right after all markup was loaded, so it kinda ignored all javascript files to load, what method do you use for this to work?

Comment: $(".text").css("visibility", "visible"); is the javascript line you want.

Just make sure you are loading any style (.css) files before you load your javascript (.js) file.

Comment: Just tried it out, even placed it after all javascript code that's responsible for ui changes, still for split second I can see that "bad" looking code. The way I do it is, I have all css files in head and than jQuery and all javascript files just before closing body tag, do I need to reposition something?

Comment: It sounds like there is either code in your javascript that is getting executed after the page loads and is being displayed, and it looks "bad" until this code is executed, or what would be more common, the code executes and the css hasn't loaded yet, so until the css loads, it looks "ugly". Is it possible you can post this example somewhere - maybe jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @IlyaKnaup Small comment about *"I even placed it after"*: JavaScript doesn't work like that (procedurally, waiting for each command to finish before passing to the next one). That's why there's an elaborate system of callbacks for firing an event after another event has finished.

Comment: @msanford cool thank you, in fact I knew that before, have no idea why I wrote it there, must be going crazy from all the work ;D

Comment: @IlyaKnaup No doubt, just mentioning it for others. And for others without much JS experience, it can be easy to fall back into that procedural mindset. Happens to me too sometimes.